# Shaking or jittering app when running in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

In Chrome 66, when I run my Cypress tests in the Test Runner, my app seems to be shaking, possibly caused by the scrollbar constantly appearing and disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is seemingly a bug in Chrome 66.

If you want the AUT (app under test) to stop shaking (until Chrome issues a fix / Cypress disables this behavior by default) - you can pass this flag to Chrome: `--disable-blink-features=RootLayerScrolling`

Put the code below in your `cypress/plugins/index.js` file as a workaround.

Example Workaround Code:

```
module.exports = (on) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      args.push('--disable-blink-features=RootLayerScrolling')
      return args
    }
  })
}
```